# How can I fetch all the rows of the data?

Tags: php

I have this code in PHP:

```
if (empty($_GET)) {
        $response['code'] = 1;
        $response['status'] = $api_response_code[$response['code']]['HTTP Response'];
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM table";
        $result = $conn->query($sql);

        if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
            // output data of each row
            while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc())
                    $response['data'] = $row;
        } else
            $response['data'] = NULL;
}
```

Currently, I am taking only the last row at $response['data']. How could I transform this code in order to get all the $row values?

I tried initializing `$response['data'] = array();`
and then did `$this->response['data'] = $row;`
but it didn't do the trick.
Please note that I am a begginer in PHP.

Comment: This [SO post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7491768/get-rows-from-mysql-table-to-php-arrays) might help you..

Comment: just answered a near identical question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34981215/my-php-scripts-returns-only-one-row-from-my-table/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are overwriting your `$response['data']` with each iteration of the while fetch loop and not appending to the array. Hence, the last record is the only one retained.

Consider the following adjustment where `$data` is its own array to hold row records of the SQL query resultset. Then this entire array object can be appended to the initial `$response` array (creating a nested setup):

```
 $i = 0;
 $data = [];
 if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
     // output data of each row
     while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
            $data[$i] = $row;
            ...

            $i++;
     }
 }

 $response['data'] = $data;
```